# C++ задачка на строки

Tags: c++

> Пароль называется криптостойким, если он включает в себя и строчные
>   латинские буквы, и заглавные латинские буквы, и цифры, при этом его
>   длина должна быть не менее 8 символов. Требуется по данному паролю
>   определить, является ли он криптостойким.
>
> 1. *Вводится одна строка, состоящая только из латинских букв и цифр. Количество символов в строке не превышает 100.*
> 2. *Выведите слово «YES», если указанный пароль является криптостойким, и «NO» – в противном случае (заглавными латинскими
>      буквами).*

Comment: массив символов + regexp

Comment: Прошу внимания модераторов. Предположим, как в этом случае, автор хочет написать вопрос с нуля. Имею ли я право предложить ему решить этот вопрос через личную почту?

Comment: Что конкретно в этой задаче вызывает трудности?

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, можете пригласить его в чат, созданный здесь же)

Comment: Мне не хватает 20 баллов.))

Comment: Приглашаю в чат

Answer (score 2):

https://ideone.com/PLXadQ

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  for (string s; cin >> s; )
    cout << s << " - " << boolalpha
      << regex_match
         (
           begin(s),
           end(s),
           regex("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$")
         )
      << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: просто интересно, вы действительно считаете что регулярка - лучшее решение? Или просто привели самое короткое?

Comment: @pavel, ну вроде как самая порстая. И вообще, регулярки - унмверсальная штука для всех языков, поэтому обычно валидацию данных делают именно регулярками. Ну да, в данном случае эффективнее было бы сделать цикл, но решение с циклом лично мне писать неинтересно. PS: Это вообще один из ответов, которые я давал, чтобы добрать дневные 200 баллов)